# find duplicates in excel and replace with value

Tags: excel

hope you guys can help me.

person table:

```
ID     | FIRST NAME   | LAST NAME     | COUNTRY-TEXT   | COUNTRY-ID
-------+--------------+---------------+----------------+---------------
1      | John         | Doe           | Austria        | ??
2      | Jane         | Doe           | Other          | ??
```

country table:

```
ID     | COUNTRY
-------+----------------------
1      | United Kingdom
2      | Austria
3      | Other
```

I usually end up knowing the name of the country - as in this case, Austria/Other, but I don't know the ID. The List country has about 200 entries. Is there any function I could use to find the country name in the country table, look at the id and paste the id back into the country-id cell in my person table?

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks pnuts!

With INDEX/MATCH I was able to find my id! Thanks again for the hint!!

In case anyone ever has the same problem:

```
=INDEX(Country!$A$2:$A$206;MATCH(I2;Country!$B$2:$B$206;0))

Country!$A$2:$A$206    -> Country Table with Search Area (ID)
I2                     -> Country-Text in Person Table 
Country!$B$2:$B$206    -> Country Text
```